# Can we get code format of barcode by passing the barcode value?

Tags: java, android, barcode, zxing

I am using ZXING library in android studio to scan and retrieve barcode value and code format of a barcode. But if i have only a barcode value like "0123456789" can i know the code format of it by passing string? Is there any library/ method which takes barcode value as input and returns its code format as output?

I have tried searching google in many forms.No luck.

Comment: Code formats? You mean `EAN13`, `EAN8`, `UPC-A`, `UPC-E` and so on?

Comment: Yes @ArnaudDenoyelle code formats like Code 39,EAN13 etc

Comment: Barcode value is plain string, by having the value only, it is not possible to know the Barcode Format.

Comment: Thanks for ur comment @GauravKP do u mean that we can get code format only by scanning barcode image?